# mandrill api messages/info multiple id

Tags: api, mandrill

I'm developing an simple php application using mandrill APIs.
Is possible to retrieve multiple messages/info using multiple id in single call?

```
{
    "key": "example key",
    "id": "abc123abc123abc123abc123"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their API its not possible using the messages/info and a list of IDs.

You can use messages/search and narrow it down, to match only the mails you want, altough its not filtering based on IDs, but on more general conditions, but in most cases its sufficent for the task.

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html